# How Can I to Change Text Size in RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-widget, text-size, remoteview

Under RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    final int itemId = (position % 2 == 0 ? R.layout.light_widget_item
            : R.layout.dark_widget_item);
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), itemId);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_item, text);
    // rv.setTextSize(mPrefs.getTextsize().getValue());
    return rv;
}
```

How can I change the text size programmatically?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about the `setFloat()` method?

```
rv.setFloat(R.id.widget_item, "setTextSize", mPrefs.getTextsize().getValue());
```

Comment: Since API level 16 there's a [setTextViewTextSize(R.id.x, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setTextViewTextSize%28int,%20int,%20float%29)