# Crash setTextViewTextSize in a widget only without Jelly Bean

Tags: android, widget, remoteview

I am making a widget in which you can specify the text size

> controles.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.LblMsg, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
>   textSize);

I am working with android 4.1

> android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="16"

The problem is that it works correctly in android 4.1, but in any other version (ICS, gingerbread, etc) shows a forced close.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   android.widget.RemoteViews.setTextViewTextSize

If I remove the line of code where it is used "setTextViewTextSize", the application works perfectly.

I find no information about the reason for this error.

I appreciate any help.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is only available since API level 16 (android 4.1) : [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setTextViewTextSize(int, int, float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setTextViewTextSize%28int,%20int,%20float%29)

Comment: and what is the method that I can use in earlier versions of android? thanks

Comment: Chech this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721616/how-to-change-textsize-in-remoteviews

Answer (score 7):

if you wish to use something that works on all versions, use this:

```
remoteViews.setFloat(R.id.textView,"setTextSize",fontSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
   remoteViews.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.price, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 100f);
}
```

Comment: this solutions works but don't forget that last param is `float` - so we must use `f` at the end, it will be like:
 `remoteViews.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.price, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 100f);`