# Android home screen widget textsize dynamically

Tags: android, android-widget, android-remoteview

There are applications that offer the ability to change the font size of a text in a home screen widget. One example is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zooper.zwfree

However home screen widgets only can carry `RemoteView`s so setting the `textSize` of a `TextView` *dynamically* will not work.

As I see it there are two possibilities to change the text size dynamically:

- Add for every text size another layout.xml file. Those files merely differ in the `TextView`'s `textSize` value. When the user wants to change the textsize, the respective layout has to be loaded.
- Draw a Bitmap instead of creating a View like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4411060/883083

My question is: Is there a third possibility left?

Comment: This might be a solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721616/how-can-i-to-change-text-size-in-remoteviews

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting API level 16 or above, you can try the following:

Sadly the whole thing depends on knowing the widget size, which is only possible in API 16+.

1. Override the [AppWidgetProvider.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(android.content.Context,+android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager,+int,+android.os.Bundle)) callback
   or get the same Bundle later via [AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#getAppWidgetOptions(int))
2. Extract the size of the widget:

   - `options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH)`
   - `options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH)`
   - `options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT)`
   - `options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT)`
3. Deduce your `TextView`'s width from the widget size
   (best if you have it `match_parent` to the root of the widget, mind margins/paddings)
4. If you have  complex layout you can alternatively

   - inflate the whole widget in your app space
     `widget = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.widget, null)`
   - Simulate a layout based on [the framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html):
     `widget.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widgetWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), ...)`.
   - Get your `TextView`'s size: `widget.findViewById(R.id.myText).getMeasuredWidth()`
5. Use something like [`refitText` here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview) to find your optimal size
6. Set the calculated size via [RemoteViews.setTextViewTextSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setTextViewTextSize%28int,+int,+float%29)

*Note: I didn't implement this method, just thought about it.*

**Try not to do this on every update, cache the results (even in preferences), widget options shouldn't change often.**